# CSV to JSON in spring boot with multiple types of records

Tags: json, spring-boot, csv

I have a requirement to parse a CSV file with 1 header record (no Names), one to many detail records and one tail record as follows (input.csv) which needs to be converted into the output.json format.

I have used the below opencsv library to read the records into List of Array of string where each String array in the List represents 1 record.

There is also a bean mapping given in the opencsv but it doesn't have the facility to map the header record into a separate Bean, details records into array of separate beans and tail record into another separate bean.

http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#reading_without_annotations_column_positions

So I am now stuck to produce the Json from the CSV with a Header, Multiple Detail and One Tail record.

Could someone please share some ideas to achieve this?

input.csv

```
1,,,

2,DC PIV REL11,D6,

2,DC PIV REL12,ADDED VIA SFTP12,

2,D6,ADDED VIA SFTP6,

3,123,END
```

output.json

```
{
    "header": {
    "type": "1",
    "number": "",
    "code": ""
},
{
  "contents": {
    "content": [
      {
        "type": "2",
        "name": "DC PIV REL11",
        "reference": "D6"
      },
      {
        "type": "2",
        "name": "DC PIV REL12",
        "reference": "ADDED VIA SFTP12"
      },
      {
        "type": "2",
        "name": "D6",
        "reference": "ADDED VIA SFTP6"
      }
    ]
},
{ 
"tail": {
    "type": "3",
    "number": "123",
    "code": "END"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the following solution.

I have created 4 DTO classes Root, Header, Contents and Tail with appropriate getter setters and used the below code to solve the problem.

Please Note, I haven't added the validation logic to check whether the record is header, content or tail record in the below code as I assumed the first record is header last but one records are contents and last record is tail.

Hope this helps.

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(classLoader.getResource("sample_file.txt").getFile()));


    List<String[]> records = reader.readAll();

    int count = 0;
    Header header = new Header();
    Contents contents = new Contents();
    Tail tail = new Tail();
    List<Content> contentList = new ArrayList<Content>();
    for (String[] record : records) {

        if (count == 0 ) {

            header.setRecordType(record[0]);
            header.setNumber(record[1]);
            header.setCode(record[2]);              
        } else if (count < (records.size() - 1)) {

            Content content = new Content();
            content.setRecordType(record[0]);
            content.setName(record[1]);
            content.setReference(record[2]);

            contentList.add(content);
        } else {

            tail.setRecordType(record[0]);
            tail.setNumber(record[1]);
            tail.setCode(record[2]);

        }
        count++;

    }
    contents.setContent(contentList);

    Root root = new Root();
    root.setHeader(header);
    root.setContents(contents);
    root.setTail(tail);
```